# ZF2 - ServiceManager & getServiceConfig problems - unable to fetch or create instance

Tags: phpunit, zend-framework2

I am coming across some problems when trying to use ZF2's authentication services. I have to following Module.php getServiceConfig function:

```
<?php

public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Auth\Model\CustomerTable' =>  function($sm) {
                $tableGateway = $sm->get('CustomerTableGateway');
                $table = new CustomerTable($tableGateway);
                return $table;
            },
            'CustomerTableGateway' => function($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Customer()); // prototype pattern implemented.
                return new TableGateway('customer', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
            },
            'Auth\Model\AuthStorage' => function($sm){
                return new \Auth\Model\AuthStorage('jamietech');  
            },
            'AuthService' => function($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $dbTableAuthAdapter  = new DbTableAuthAdapter($dbAdapter, 
                                          'customer','username','password');

                $authService = new AuthenticationService();
                $authService->setAdapter($dbTableAuthAdapter);
                $authService->setStorage($sm->get('Auth\Model\AuthStorage'));

                return $authService;
            },
        ),
    );
}
```

The AuthStorage factory simply creates a new AuthStorage for us to keep track of the rememberMe function I have, and the AuthService factory creates a new Authentication Service for us. I can't see anything that I have done wrong but when running the following code in the AuthController.php:

```
<?php

public function loginAction()
{
    //if already login, redirect to success page 

    if ($this->getAuthService()->hasIdentity()){
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('success');
    }

    $form = new LoginForm();
    return array(
        'form'     => $form,
        'messages' => $this->flashmessenger()->getMessages()
    );
}

public function logoutAction()
{
    $this->getSessionStorage()->forgetMe();
    $this->getAuthService()->clearIdentity();
    $this->flashmessenger()->addMessage("You have logged out successfully.");

    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('auth', array('action'=>'login'));
}
```

PHPUnit encounters the following errors when running the PHPUnit command:

```
1: "testLoginActionCanBeAccessed - Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance of Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter

1: "testLogoutActionCanBeAccessed - session_regenerate_id(): cannot regenerate session id - headers already sent.
```

And this error for both login and logout when the -process-isolation command is run:

```
"Serialization of closure is not allowed in: C;\Users\-----\AppData\Local\Temp\-----
```

If somebody could help that would be great. I am a ZF noob so try not to be too harsh.

EDIT: BTW THe global.php file includes the service_manager adapter factory illustrated in the ZF2 tutorial application.

Thank you!
Jamie Mclaughlan

Comment: I have the same problem. How did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

did you check these:

- autoload_classmap.php (for your module)
- in your **module.config.php**

like this

```
service_manager' => array(
 'aliases' => array(    
  'mymodule-ZendDbAdapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter',
  ),
);
```

I hope it helps you to find the answer

Comment: Hi, I really appreciate your reply.

My autoload_classmap.php is just an empty array, and the module.config includes the service_manager and its adapter is included in the global.php file. I'm still unsure as to what could be causing the problem.

Comment: Also, I am able to create an Adapter in one my AuthTableGateway factory within the module class, but it won't allow me to create another in the AuthService class. I'm so confused!